# How to check whether a button is disabled using typescript and angular 2

Tags: angular, button

I am trying to enable buttonA if buttonB is not disabled (of course there are other conditions not relevant to question).  I need to determine in my typescript whether buttonB is disabled.  Obviously you can't use this.buttonB.nativeElement.disabled == true .... I just put it in as a placeholder.  I am using Angular 2.

@ViewChild('buttonB') buttonB;

```
if (this.buttonB.nativeElement.disabled == true){
  console.log('Button B is enabled');
} else console.log('Button is disabled');
```

Comment: Can you provide the html of the button block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it.

First, you use [Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) (Or document.getElementById(), getElementsByTagName(), etc) to retrieve the button Element (lets assume it has a class of `buttonA`). Next, you can simply access its attributes and check its values.

If you want to check its `disabled` attributes, you can simply do check for the value in `button['disabled']`.

```
const button = document.querySelector('.buttonA');
console.log(button['disabled']) //prints true or false
```